# Tasks/instructions? A question on teachers' vocabulary

Tags: vocabulary, teaching

Each exercise given in a textbook is accompanied by instructions. Is it acceptable to call them also "tasks"?

Comment: Yes it is acceptable. Why do you think that it might not be acceptable?

Comment: I am not sure because I am not familiar with the terminology.

Comment: It's fine. You can call them tasks.

Comment: Are you asking if you can say "Each exercise given in a textbook is accompanied by *tasks*"? Then no, because the [*task*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/task) is doing the exercise(s), not the information on how to do them.

Comment: @user3169: As far as I know, teachers differentiate between exercises, tasks and activities. But I am not sure if instructions can be called "a task" though they depict tasks. It's a kind of metonymy, if you like.

Comment: It's definitely acceptable, though the subjective meaning of "task" is something a bit longer to do, and potentially less fun, than an exercise.